# How to copy the memory allocated in device function back to main memory

Tags: cuda

I have a CUDA program containing a host function and a device function ***Execute()***. In the host function, I allocate a global memory ***output*** which will then be passed to the device function and used to store the address of the global memory allocated within the device function. I want to access the in-kernel allocated memory in the host function. The following is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct                      
{
  int             * p;            
  int              num;            
} Structure_A;

__global__ void Execute(Structure_A *output);

int main(){

    Structure_A *output;
    cudaMalloc((void***)&output,sizeof(Structure_A)*1);
    dim3 dimBlockExecute(1,1);
    dim3 dimGridExecute(1,1);
    Execute<<<dimGridExecute,dimBlockExecute>>>(output);
    Structure_A * output_cpu;
    int * p_cpu;
    cudaError_t err;

    output_cpu= (Structure_A*)malloc(sizeof(Structure_A));
    err=cudaMemcpy(output_cpu,output,sizeof(Structure_A),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);    
    if( err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA error a: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
    p_cpu=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    err=cudaMemcpy(p_cpu,output_cpu[0].p,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);    
    if( err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA error b: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }   
    printf("output=(%d,%d)\n",output_cpu[0].num,p_cpu[0]);
    return 0;
}

__global__ void Execute(Structure_A *output){

    int thid=threadIdx.x;

    output[thid].p= (int*)malloc(thid+1);

    output[thid].num=(thid+1);

    output[thid].p[0]=5;
}
```

I can compile the program. But when I run it, I got a error showing that there is a invalid argument in the following memory copy function:

```
err=cudaMemcpy(p_cpu,output_cpu[0].p,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

CUDA version is 4.2. 
CUDA card: Tesla C2075
OS: x86_64 GNU/Linux

Edit: modified the code and allocate proper size of memory for output_cpu and p_cpu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many things wrong with this code. For example, you are only allocating 1 byte in both of these two lines, not enough to hold a single instance of `Structure_A`.

```
output_cpu= (Structure_A*)malloc(1);
p_cpu=(int *)malloc(1);
```

But the immediate cause of your error is that you are doing a memcpy from a device runtime heap allocated pointer (i.e allocated with `malloc` or `new` inside your device code) to a host pointer.

```
err=cudaMemcpy(p_cpu,output_cpu[0].p,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

Unfortunately the host runtime API for cudaMalloc, cudaFree, and cudaMemcpy is not currently compatible with memory allocated on the device runtime heap.

Comment: Your last pointer isn't correct. `output_cpu[0].p` is a device pointer, but it is allocated on runtime heap, so API device to host transfers are not supported.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't obvious to me that the OP was calling malloc/new on the device, since OP didn't include any kernel code. Should have read more carefully.  I have edited the OP's code to make this clear.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I thought that since we can have a device pointer to store the address of the global memory allocated using the cudaMalloc function, and use the cudaMemcpy function to copy the value in that global memory back to main memory, we should be able to do the same thing for the global memory allocated on runtime heap.

Comment: Now I understand the global memory allocated on runtime heap cannot be copied back to main memory. But what is the point of allocating memory that we can't access from host function?

Comment: @xhe8: The point is that you can access it from the device. It is often more efficient to write an initialisation kernel to set up and populate complex structures in GPU memory, then process them in the GPU, and finally "flatten out" the results for transfer back to the host than it is to try and use the host APIs to do the same task.